# Add field to sales_flat_order

Tags: zend-framework, magento

I'm trying to add a new field to the sales_flat_order table via a module I'm making. I've tried to run the setup script but it doesn't seem to be changing the table at all.

Here is the update script:

mysql4-upgrade-0.1.1-0.1.2.php

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales_flat_order'), 'expected_delivery_date', 'datetime');
```

Here is my config.xml

```
...

<modules>
    <Optimiseweb_OrderPad>
        <version>0.1.2</version>
    </Optimiseweb_OrderPad>
</modules>


...
<resources>
  <orderpad>
      <setup>
          <module>Optimiseweb_Orderpad</module>
          <class>Optimiseweb_Orderpad_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
      </setup>
  </orderpad>
</resources>

<models>
  <orderpad>
    <class>Mage_Sales_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>orderpad_mysql4</resourceModel>
  </orderpad>
  <orderpad_mysql4>
           <class>Optimiseweb_Orderpad_Model_Mysql4</class>
           <entities>
               <order><table>sales_flat_order</table></order>
           </entities>
  </orderpad_mysql4>
</models>
...
```

The two models referred to in the config.xml

Optimiseweb/Orderpad/Model/Mysql4.php

```
<?php

class Optimiseweb_Orderpad_Model_Mysql4 extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{



}
```

Optimiseweb/Orderpad/Model/Mysql4/Setup.php

```
<?php

class Optimiseweb_Orderpad_Model_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup
{



}
```

Anyhelp to add the new field to the orders table would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to add a column to a flat sales table, it is better to do via adding an attribute to a sales entity (sales_order). Make sure that your install modell `Optimiseweb_Orderpad_Model_Mysql4_Setup` extends  `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup` and execute

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('order', 'expected_delivery_date', array('type'=>'datetime'));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this this morning and post the results

Comment: I have tried this, but not sure if I'm testing it properly. I ran the update and now am trying this: ```$orderId = 5;

      $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
      $order->setExpectedDeliveryDate(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
      $order->save();``` but when I do a vardump ```order->getExpectedDeliveryDate()``` I just get NULL

Comment: That is strange. I've tested it in my test shop just now. I've got a new column in the order flat table. Also I was able to set and get the attribute value:

Comment: require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(1);
$order->setExpectedDeliveryDate(now());
$order->save();
$date = $order->getExpectedDeliveryDate();
echo $date;

Comment: does your table have the new column now?

Comment: Hi Oleg, sorry which table should it be in?

Comment: sales_flat_order, if the column is not there, then the update script didn't run

Comment: yeah there's something wrong with the config I guess. The module isn't listed in core_resources either. It's displayed in the module list in system > config > advanced though